# Why does Keypoint_convert fail if applied twice?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do operations on point descriptors on an image, and while doing so it's useful to get a numpy representation of the 2D coordinates of my keypoints, applying some linear transformation to it and convert it back to a list of `cv2.KeyPoint` objects.

I seem to fail to do so, and my problem seems to boil down to the fact that in the code

```
import cv2
import imutils

img = imutils.url_to_image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png') 
detector = cv2.AKAZE_create()
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
kpts, desc = detector.detectAndCompute(gray_image, None)
coords = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kpts)

# here I would to stuff with coords   
# and then finally 
transformed_kpts = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(coords)
```

the last line fails to execute.

Simplifying things even further, doing something as simple as

```
cv2.KeyPoint_convert(cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kpts))
```

crashes with

> OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:254: error:
> (-215:Assertion failed) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function
> 'copyTo'

Is this a bug or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html#acfcc8e0dd1a634a7583686e18d372237) it looks to me that the applying the function twice on a list of keypoints should run fine and give me back the original list.

My `cv2.__version__` is 4.1.2.

EDIT: This doesn't reproduce with a more recent version of `python-opencv` like `4.8.0`. Upgrading to a more recent version results makes the code behave as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kpts) -> pts2f` is a `(n,2)` ndarray
The input of `cv2.KeyPoint_convert(pts2f) -> kpts` should be a `(n,1,2)` ndarray

Therefore, to run your snippet, you need to reshape the first output as in

```py
kpts, desc = detector.detectAndCompute(gray_image, None)
coords = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kpts)
transformed_kpts = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(coords.reshape(len(kpts), 1, 2))
```

You can verify that `kpts` and `transformed_kpts` are the same with

```py
all([transformed_kpts[i].pt == kpts[i].pt for i in range(len(kpts))])
```

Comment: Also you can add the link to the documentation where people can read more about it.